# how to define JSON schema for array?

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have this JSON file:

```
    {  
        "tcCensusTractBlockFacesStatefp":"01",
        "tcCensusTractBlockFacesCountyfp":"001",
        "tcCensusTractBlockFacesTractce":"020200",
        "tcCensusTractBlockFacesBlockce10":"2022",
        "tcCensusTractBlockFacesGeoid":"010010202002022",
        "cellIDs":[  
        9839958675010879488,
        9839958675082706944,
        9839958677655912448,
        9839958677556297728,
        9839958676975910912,
        9839958677063991296,
        9839958677105934336,
        9839958679922409472,
        9839958679922933760,
        9839958679975886848,
        9839958679979032576,
        9839958679461036032,
        9839958679450550272,
        9839958678956670976,
        9839958678926262272,
        9839958667678187520,
        9839958667562844160,
        9839958675010879488
        ]
    }
```

How to define the schema to import it in BigQuery like this?

```
bq mk --table $DATASET:$TABLE tl_2017_schema.json
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON $DATASET:$TABLE $WNAME
```

### Here is what I tried to do:

tl_2017_schema.json

```
...
---
     {
        "name": "cellIDs",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "cellID",
                "type": "INT64",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    }
...
```

But this part responsible for the ARRAY cannot match the arrays structure I have in the JSON file:

"cellIDs":[
    9839958675010879488,
    9839958675082706944,
    9839958677655912448,
    9839958677556297728,
    9839958676975910912,
    9839958677063991296,
    9839958677105934336,
    9839958679922409472,
    9839958679922933760,
    9839958679975886848,
    9839958679979032576,
    9839958679461036032,
    9839958679450550272,
    9839958678956670976,
    9839958678926262272,
    9839958667678187520,
    9839958667562844160,
    9839958675010879488
]

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier just to run a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language):

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.tablename
(
  ...
  cellIDs ARRAY<INT64>
)
```

If you really want to specify the schema as JSON, the fix in your example is to make the `cellIDs` a `REPEATED` `INTEGER` type:

```
{
    "name": "cellIDs",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REPEATED"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked just perfect:
    {
        "name": "cellIDs",
        "type": "NUMERIC",
        "mode": "REPEATED"       
    }
]